# Determinant of a $58 \times 58$ block matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, block-matrices

Given a $58 \times 58$ block matrix :
$\mspace{20mu}A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 &  R\\ 
0 & Q & T\\ 
P & S & U
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{58\times 58} $,

$P\in \mathbb{R}^{11\times 11}\mspace{10mu},\mspace{10mu}Q\in \mathbb{R}^{28\times 28}\mspace{10mu},\mspace{10mu}R\in \mathbb{R}^{19\times 19},$

$\det(P)=p \mspace{10mu},\mspace{10mu}\det(Q)=q \mspace{10mu},\mspace{10mu}\det(r)=r  \\ \\
\det(A)=??$

I have no idea how to find the determinant.

Answer (score 5):

First note that your matrix can be expressed as a permutation of an upper-triangular block matrix.

$$
A = \Pi A' = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & I_{19}\\ 
0 & I_{28} & 0\\ 
I_{11} & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}
P & S & U \\
0 & Q & T \\
0 & 0 &  R
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 &  R\\ 
0 & Q & T\\ 
P & S & U
\end{bmatrix}. $$

Now use the following facts:

1. The determinant of an upper triangular of a block matrix is the [product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices) of the determinants of the blocks in the diagonal.
2. The determinant of a product is the product of the determinants.
3. The elementary row operation of swapping two rows flips the sign of the determinant. Since $\Pi$ is obtained by performing an odd number of such operations on the identity, $det(\Pi)=-1$.

This yields
$$
det(A)=det(\Pi)det(A')=-pqr.
$$

Comment: I guess you should say more about $\det(\Pi)$.

Comment: @WhatsUp There. I hope I didn't mess up the sign...

Comment: Now it looks good to me.